# While converting NSString to String my result changes

Tags: ios, swift

I request you to give me a solution where the result of `NSString` and `String` both are same

> downloadedFile = MOM'&^*%s-HC.pdf (In NSString)

```
let path = pathComponent.appendingPathComponent(downloadedFile as String)
print(path) //OutPut:  ttt_gmail_com/MOM'&%5E*%25s-HC-2.pdf
```

If I test with `regular expression` result is OK.

```
let NSStringValue = "MOM'&^*%s-HC.pdf" as NSString
print(NSStringValue) // Output: MOM'&^*%s-HC.pdf
let StringValue = downloadedFile as String
print(StringValue) // Output: MOM'&^*%s-HC.pdf
```

but while I put that code in `appendingPathComponent` it changes my result.

Comment: So your filename contains characters that are not allowed in an Url. What exactly is the problem with that?

Comment: I honestly don't know what is the question. Invalid characters in paths are encoded.

Comment: Do you want the actual ***string***? Or, do you want a usable filename / URL?

Comment: @tushar welcome to SO. The result you are getting is expected. The `^` and `%` characters are being URL percent encoded by the `appendingPathComponent` API.

Comment: There's no issue here. The string is just being stored using [Percent-encoding/URL Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) format. If you're only concerned about the way it prints to console then you can do `string.removingPercentEncoding`. But rest assured it's valid and will work as a normal `URL` object.

Comment: your "pathComponent" must contains some path itself, print value of "pathComponent" in console.
take new variable and then try this

let path = pathComponentNewVariable.appendingPathComponent(downloadedFile as String)
print(path)

Comment: @ Joakim: pdf is having the name "MOM'&^*%s-HC.pdf" it's not a Url  & I download that file from dropbox, & I want to store that PDF in the local device that's why i convert NSString to String.

Comment: But you are doing `pathComponent.appendingPathComponent` which returns an URL object and you can then use that object when storing your file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a file name which has all the special characters here, I tried your case in a sample project trying to load such file in `UIDocumentInteractionController` and it seems when I have a file name with special character in my document directory and i try to retrieve it, few special characters are URL encoded.

Observe the file name I used here is "MOM'&^*%s-HC.pdf" and saved it in the doc directory but when I retrieve it from the document directory using the following code few characters are URL encoded as I am fetching the path as URL.

So this means that your original file name

> MOM'&^*%s-HC.pdf

is now alterated and replaced by percentage escape sequence strings,

> MOM'&%5E*%25s-HC.pdf

observe the below code which I used

```
var pdfURL = (FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)).last! as URL
        pdfURL = pdfURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
```

[image: Output]

To resolve this all i did was removed the percentage escape sequence when I am creating the URL and it worked I was able to view the PDF in the `UIDocumentInteractionController`

```
fileName.removingPercentEncoding!
```

Hope it helps.